# How to have multiple data adapter in one ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, listadapter

```
 adapterListView = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(),list,R.layout.listview_layout,from,to);
 adapterListViewCash = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(),list,R.layout.jpos_cash_adapter,fromCash,toCash);
```

> is it possible to have multiple adapter in one list view i want to implement something like this...

```
        lv.addHeaderView(headerView);
        lv.addFooterView(footerView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapterListView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapterListViewCash);
```

> i know it's an error but how can i implement something like this?
>
> I want to do this because my objects in list view has 6 format.. how can i manipulate my item adapter layout?

Comment: You should use one listview for the header and a different listview for the footer.

Comment: yes i did that right but all i want here is to have multiple data adapter for my list view because i have different format to be display per list item.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. what are you actully trying to do?

Comment: i want to call different format in displaying item in my adapter.. like item Adapter one can have 2 TextView and some layout format... item Adapter two has 5 different Objects and some layout format and item Adapter3,4,5,6, and so on with different format and objects...

Answer (score 2):

CommonsWare has created an adapter that does just that. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge